# ASP.NET MVC redirect to logon page always

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership

I am using ASP.NET independent membership in my own way. To achieve it, I set FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie when user has logged in my system and i also removed all membership relation configurations like profile, role and membership settings from web.config.

Problem is that i can not access any controller. ASP.NET MVC redirect me to /Account/Logon page but even i can not catch breakpoint in LogOn action method and i dont see any content parsed as a result.

What can cause this strange behavior really ? Please ask if you need extra information to understand problem.

My web.config settings are at below.

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>

  </configSections>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="1.0.0.0" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="enableSimpleMembership" value="false" />
    <add key="autoFormsAuthentication" value="false" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <globalization uiCulture="tr-TR" culture="tr-TR" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,  PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,       PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,       PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,           PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,      PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
        <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
    <httpModules></httpModules>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"></modules>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.8.0" newVersion="4.0.8.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Please add your AuthorizationFilter to tell the way that you consider an User is Authenticated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you say you aren't hitting a breakpoint in your Logon Post action, it would suggest that you have `AuthoriseAttribute` set on the Logon Post method (or set globally in `RegisterGlobalFilters`).  The Logon Post method needs to be accessibly Anonymously, or it won't be able to receive the username and password.

I'd suggest you post the relevant Actions from your Account controller, and the contents of your Global.asax RegisterGlobalFilters method if this doesn't help,

Comment: I appreciate your effort. I had guessed same things with you but i couldnt see any global filter registered for that. I just have seen that there is authorize attribute on controller and i already removed it but result was same. Now after read your answer i started to inspect where it is. Because i am not only person who coded project. I have seen that someone has been put Authorize over my BaseController huhhhh...

Comment: It's better to put your `AuthorizeAttribute` in RegisterGlobalFilters if your app mostly requires authentication.  There's a good post at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2011/05/02/securing-your-asp-net-mvc-3-application.aspx which describes the use of an `AllowAnonymous` attribute you can put on your Logon actions (this is built into MVC4, and is much better).

Comment: I exactly gone same way with this article but from another's article and i named it "DisableAuthorize" but "AllowAnonymous" can better name :)

Comment: When you upgrade to MVC4, you can just use the system-provided AllowAnonymous - this works with the normal AuthorizeAttribute so you don't need to bother writing your own

Answer (score 0):

Exactly like Richard mentioned, I think this article also shows you how to apply the AllowAnonymousAttribute with AuthoriseAttribute applied for your MVC project. 
http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2012/04/18/asp-net-mvc-authentication-global-authentication-and-allow-anonymous.aspx